# SQL Server search query to read only limited rows after adding top in select condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have table with active records as 1700 when we are taking top 25 rows

```
select top 25 * from table where isactive=1
```

Num of rows and estimated Num of rows both are same that is 25 in actual execution plan.

But when are taking only pending rows it was searching for whole active records

```
select top 25 * from table where isactive=1 and pending=1
```

Num of rows read is 1700 and estimated Num of rows are 25 in actual execution plan when we add pending condition.

I want a query even though after adding pending=1 condition also the Num of rows read should be 25 only in actual execution plan.

Comment: Presumably you have no index on `pending`, and thus the entire table must be scanned to find 25 arbitrary rows, but you have an index on `isactive` and thus a seek to return 25 arbitrary rows can be completed.

Comment: You can include `pending` in your existing index on `isactive`, presumably it's a `bit` or `tinyint` and will add negligibly to the index. `create index <name> on <table> (isactive) include (pending) with(drop_existing=on)`

Comment: Use of TOP without an order by clause is generally a logic flaw. Be certain you understand the consequences of not using an ORDER by clause.

Comment: create index <name> on <table> (isactive) include (pending) with(drop_existing=on) yeah we have index but it was not working

Comment: I use select top  x when I quickly need a couple of rows for testing. I use select  top 1 when I need to go through a small table one row at a time. It is not necessarily a logic flaw. I also used  'top 10000' when I want to batch deletes.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits And that is why i wrote "generally". If you understand how TOP works and accept that does not always include the same rows, then run with it. But you are not OP - that comment is not directed at someone with significant skill and experience.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already have an index like the below.

```
create index idx_table_isactive on table(isactive) include (pending) with(drop_existing=on)

create index idx_table_isactive on table(isactive,pending)  with(drop_existing=on)
```

Don't use * on your Select statement. Your index will not be utilized properly if you have * (All columns from your table). Try like the below provided any one of the index is in place.

```
SELECT TOP 25 isactive,
    pending 
FROM table 
WHERE isactive=1 
    AND pending=1
```